# when using Devel::Cover, difference between ./Build test and cover -t

Tags: unit-testing, perl, code-coverage

I'm looking to determine coverage of some unit tests.  The project requires a second directory (basically from a GitHub repository) and when running everything, I usually add the 2nd lib directory with

```
use lib "/path/to/second/dir/lib";
```

and currently I have this in the `Build.PL` file (I'm using `Module::Build`). Running `./Build test` gives a nice summary of all of the test (about 10 files-worth), however, running `cover -test` gives me errors, specifically, a

```
Can't use an undefined value as a symbol reference at XXX
```

which is a file in that second directory.

Is this because it appears that the `Module::Build` tends to copy files to the `blib` directory?  If so, does it use the files there?  What are the other differences between running `cover -test` and `./Build test`?

Comment: According to [the documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel::Cover) you should run `./Build testcover` and not `cover -t` ?

Comment: I guess because the setup uses `Module::Build`.  I successfully run tests using `./Build test`, but there are errors like `Devel::Cover: Warning: can't open Specio::Coercion->_coercion for MD5 digest: No such file or directory` when running `./Build testcover`

Comment: Please provide a minimal version of your test files and the module/script you are testing. Then we can try to reproduce. See [mcve] for more information

Comment: The code is a bit too large to develop a minimal reproducible example, so I am rewriting to limit the effect of the second repository.  I'm hoping after this that the errors will go away.